# ng-show only for admin in meanjs.

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

In `view.article.view.html` i want to show html tag only if the authenticated user is admin. I tried to do so like below, but it did not work.

```
<p ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=admin">show only for admin </p>
```

Comment: What does your `.roles` property look like? At least it should look like `.roles == 'admin'` (double == and quotes around admin), but `roles` sounds like a multiple, so maybe `.roles.indexOf('admin') > -1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer,double equals works, if you can write it as an answer i will tick mark it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=admin"`

should be

`ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=='admin'"` or `===`

Comment: how to use one or more roles in this above answer, for example i just want to use onemore role like 'kp' , I have tried like :- `ng-show="vm.authentication.user.roles=='admin', ' kp'"` but it's not working for me please help us... thanks.

Comment: `vm.authentication.user.roles=='admin' || vm.authentication.user.roles=='kp'`
 If your html gets too much cluttered, make youself a function. The ng-show is merely an "if" statement that shows the content if the expression returns `true` or `false`